# redux-api-middleware throws fetch is not defined

Tags: redux, jestjs, redux-api-middleware

I recently upgraded `redux-api-middleware` from 2.3.0 to 3.0.1 When running my tests with `jest@22.2.1` I get this `ReferenceError`:

```
ReferenceError: fetch is not defined

  19 | export function sortPolicyChain (payload: Array<ChainPolicy>): SortPolicyChainAction {
  20 |   return { type: 'SORT_POLICY_CHAIN', payload }
> 21 | }
  22 |
  23 | export type UpdatePolicyInChainAction = { type: 'UPDATE_POLICY_IN_CHAIN', policyConfig: ChainPolicy }
  24 | export function updatePolicyInChain (policyConfig: ChainPolicy): UpdatePolicyInChainAction {

  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/redux-api-middleware/lib/index.cjs.js:404:3)
  at Object.<anonymous> (app/javascript/src/Policies/actions/PolicyChain.jsx:21:27)
  at Object.<anonymous> (spec/javascripts/Policies/actions/PolicyChain.spec.jsx:3:20)
```

The stacktrace points to this line in **PolicyChain.jsx**:

```
export function fetchChain (serviceId: string): RSSAAction {
  return {
    [RSAA]: {
      endpoint: `/admin/api/services/${serviceId}/proxy/policies.json`,
      method: 'GET',
      credentials: 'same-origin',
      types: [REQUEST, SUCCESS, FAILURE]
    }
  }
}
```

According to the [documentation here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-api-middleware#rsaafetch):

> If provided, the fetch option must be a function that conforms to the
>   Fetch API. **Otherwise, the global fetch will be used.**

But it looks like the global fetch can't be found. Any ideas?

Codebase can be found in [github](https://github.com/3scale/porta/pull/463/files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because Jest runs inside of Node.js, which doesn't have a global `fetch()`. You can fix this by installing `isomorphic-fetch` and adding this to your Jest `setupFiles`:

`require('isomorphic-fetch');`

Comment: But i didn't need that in 2.3.0 :/ did something happened?

Comment: Something must have changed. I didn't dig into it, just found how to fix it.

Comment: Looks like it works without installing that package, simply by mocking global.fetch. Do you know of any bad consequence of this? I will gladly accept your answer if you could elaborate a bit more.

Comment: There shouldn't be any issues. I use [fetch-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-mock) in all my tests, and I think it does exactly that - mock global fetch.

Comment: What I did is simply add `global.fetch = () => {}` to my `global-mocks.js`, in case you want to include it in your answer, just a suggestion :) Maybe I need a better mock in the future but for now it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Use `createMiddleware` with your own fetch compilant function

https://github.com/agraboso/redux-api-middleware#createmiddlewareoptions